# Forms9Patch - Xamarin label auto sizing - bounds autofit and initial font size

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

Using Forms9Patch in Xamarin Forms I am able to have the font dynamically resize when running on UWP and changing the size of the window horizontally.  It resizes perfectly.

However, I have a few issues that I'm not figuring out ...

1. When I shrink the window vertically, the text is not resized.  I'm doing the

   ```
   Lines = 1;
   AutoFit = Forms9Patch.AutoFit.Width;
   LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.NoWrap;
   ```

I went back here - https://baskren.github.io/Forms9Patch/guides/Label.html and re-read it.  It says to impose bounds autofitting to achieve this.  I've tried and can't get it to work.  What's the proper syntax to get this to work?

2. The starting font size for the label.  I'm hard coding that right now.  Is there a way to dynamically size it on startup?
3. I have a work around, but is there a built in way that Forms9Patch deals with screen scaling?

Comment: @baskren any clue? Btw Jimmy have you tried Lines = 0 ?

Comment: @Saamer I had tried that, but I tried it again just now.  That enabled dynamic resizing vertically.  So, my above code resizes horizontally, and using Lines=0 resizes vertically.  Now, if I can just get the two to work together ...

Comment: So changing it to 0 disables resizing horizontally?

Comment: @Saamer Yes.  The font just gets cut off when shrinking the window horizontally.  It never changes size.

Comment: Is it still an issue even if you set the `FontSize` to the maximum space available to it given the text length, playing around with Lines = 0/1

Comment: How do I set the FontSize to the maximum space available?  AutoFit.Width?  Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: just use FontSize = 24; (not MinFontSize or ActualFontSize)

Comment: I got you.  Yeah, I've done that way and it works out the same.  It works either horizontally or vertically.  But, I just saw your answer below ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could try to use something like this, where you add your private field `label` inside a `ContentView`, and then add a SizeChanged event to it

```
ContentView contentView = new ContentView
{
          Content = label
};
contentView.SizeChanged += OnContentViewSizeChanged;
```

and in the event

```
void OnContentViewSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
         string text = "Is this question similar to what you get asked at work? Learn more about asking and sharing private information with your coworkers using Stack Overflow for Teams. Is this question similar to what you get asked at work? Learn more about asking and sharing private information with your coworkers using Stack Overflow for Teams.";
         View view = (View)sender;

         // Line height is 1.2 if it's iOS or Android, but 1.3 for UWP
         double lineHeight = 1.3;
         double charWidth = 0.5;
         text = String.Format(text, lineHeight, charWidth, view.Width, view.Height);
         int charCount = text.Length;
         int fontSize = (int)Math.Sqrt(view.Width * view.Height / (charCount * lineHeight * charWidth));
         int lineCount = (int)(view.Height / (lineHeight * fontSize));
         int charsPerLine = (int)(view.Width / (charWidth * fontSize));
         label.Text = text;
         label.FontSize = fontSize;
}
```

Here's some [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05#empirically-fitting-text) that recommends it

Comment: This appears to work.  It's a great solution.  I've never seen that documentation, so thank you for that.  I've tried it out, it deals with screen scaling, and shrinking and expanding the view.  I'm still playing with it, but it looks like it will do what I was looking for.